# repcached broken sync - memcached high avalaibility

Tags: php, high-availability, memcached

I have been using repcached (memcached-1.2.8-repcached-2.2)to store php sessions in order to have a highly available memcached. Everything runs perfect, I can restart a daemon without losing sessions.

However if I reboot a server the repcached daemon does not sync to the unrebooted repcached daemon, basically they become out of sync and I would have to restart the unrebooted repcached before they would start syncing again. Even if I leave the newly booted server for hours it won't sync.

Any idea on why would this happen? Am I missing a configuration? This is the daemon config:

`/usr/local/bin/memcached -m 512 -p 11211 -u root -P /var/run/memcachedrep.pid -d -x 10.60.216.196`

Comment: I seem to end up saying this a lot, but **memcache is not designed to be highly avaliable**! If it *needs* to still exist for the duration of the timeout, don't store it in memcache. If your PHP sessions are important, don't use memcache for them. If you get a sudden spike in traffic it's possible your memcache memory will fill up and start evicting old sessions very quickly, screwing up the site for everyone.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/336592/59925