# What is the right value for memcache.session_redundancy?

Tags: memcached, php.ini, memcache, php-memcached

The [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php) for Memcache doesn't have any explanation for the `memcache.session_redundancy` option. The comment on that page (which is 4 years old) says it sets the number of copies of a session object.

In another old question on memcache [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/336592) says the the value should be N + 1, N being the no. of servers in the pool.

I'm setting up three LAMP servers to share their sessions using php5-memcache. I have left `memcache.session_redundancy` to its default 2 and it works fine.

What exactly is `memcache.session_redundancy` directive? Should I change it to 4 (3 servers + 1)?