# PHP memcached session redundancy

Tags: php, memcached, memcache, php-memcached

I'm trying to follow [How To Share PHP Sessions on Multiple Memcached Servers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-php-sessions-on-multiple-memcached-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04) article and implement that to my environment:

`/etc/php.d/memcache.ini`:

```
# grep -v ^\; /etc/php.d/memcache.ini
extension=memcache.so
memcache.allow_failover=1
memcache.session_redundancy=2
session.save_handler=memcache
session.save_path='tcp://192.168.52.143:11211, tcp://192.168.52.142:11211'
#
```

`phpinfo();`:

```
# php -i | grep -E 'memcache.allow_failover|memcache.session_redundancy|session.save_handler|session.save_path'
memcache.allow_failover => 1 => 1
memcache.session_redundancy => 2 => 2
session.save_handler => memcache => memcache
session.save_path => tcp://192.168.52.142:11211, tcp://192.168.52.143:11211 => tcp://192.168.52.142:11211, tcp://192.168.52.143:11211
#
```

both systems are `RHEL6` and running `php-5.3.3`:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
# rpm -q php php-pecl-memcache
php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
php-pecl-memcache-3.0.5-4.el6.x86_64
#
```

`TCP` wise: `.142` is able to get to `.143:11211`, and `.143` is able to get to `.142:11211`, `SELinux` is in `Permissive` mode.

I am able to see some chunks stored in one `memcached` server, but not in another.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That DigitalOcean article I wrote has `memcache.session_redundancy`, your config file has used `memcache.redundancy`, both are different and that may be the reason why it isn't working as expected.

The default value of `memcache.redundancy` is `1` and it works fine for this setup.

```
extension=memcache.so
memcache.allow_failover=1
memcache.session_redundancy=2
session.save_handler=memcache
session.save_path = 'tcp://192.168.52.143:11211,tcp://192.168.52.142:11211'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php

## Edit

Your comment:

> IP are in reverse on another server, but syntax is the same.

This is where the problem lies, the `session.save_path` **must be exact on all servers**.

So both the servers must have `'tcp://192.168.52.143:11211,tcp://192.168.52.142:11211'`

Read **Step Two** of that article, all 3 servers have the exact same order.

## Edit #2

The value of `memcache.session_redundancy` must be equal to **no. of servers + 1** due to a [bug in PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58585).

So in your case it must be:

```
memcache.session_redundancy=3
```

Comment: You're correct, I did it wrong first time( I just correct it and updated my question with correct output, however still not working for me(

Comment: @alexus Is the `session.save_path` directive exactly same on both the systems?

Comment: I tried the same settings on two CentOS 6.6 VMs and it worked without any issues. Check the `phpinfo()` page of both servers to make sure the proper configuration is in effect. And how are testing? Are you using a PHP session script?

Comment: `phpinfo();` returns correct values (I updated question with output). I'm comparing `Cache Usage` between two `memcached` server and I stated in my original question "I am able to see some chunks stored in one `memcached` server, but not in another."

Comment: Why not use the PHP script described in that article.

Comment: I'm using https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache and it doesn't matter if I'm using that project or your test `PHP` script as it's able to store chunks in one of `memcache` server, and the rest is up to `memcache.ini` configuration (variables that you described in your article).

Comment: Try the solution under **Edit #2**, it should work. I've asked DigitalOcean to update that article.

Comment: I was reading another post that describes same thing as well : http://serverfault.com/questions/164350/can-a-pool-of-memcache-daemons-be-used-to-share-sessions-more-efficiently

Comment: This answer mixes up `memcache` syntax with `memcached` options. The examples provided are not correct. Please refer to the manuals: https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.configuration.php  https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php

Answer (score -1):

Only:

```
memcache.allow_failover=1
memcache.redundancy=2
```

should be in memcache.ini.

The others should be in php.ini.

Comment: On `RHEL`, `/etc/php.d/memcache.ini` contains `memcache.allow_failover`, `memcache.redundancy` _AND_ `session.save_handler`, `session.save_path` out of the box, it's not location of variables that's causing not to work.